# Jquery Change on even function works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Scenario :**

Use has to select the right category for a website

**Issue :**

the change functions works only one time, only in one line.

**Code :**

*jQuery*

```
$('#choose').change(function(event){
    var categorie = $('#choose').val();
    var parent =  $(this).parent().parent();
    var sid = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'ajax=1&do=updatewebsite&cid='+sid+'&categorie='+categorie,
        success: function(data) {
            var status = data.split('|-|')[0];
            var message = data.split('|-|')[1];
            $('#notice').removeClass('error').removeClass('success');
            $('#notice').html('<div>'+ message +'</div>').addClass(status);
            $('#notice').fadeIn().animate({opacity:1}, 5000, 'linear', function(){$(this).fadeOut();});
            $(parent).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        }
    });
});
```

**Screenshot :**

[image: Illustration of the application]

**Question :**

what's the wrong part of the code that makes only the first action possible?

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs?

Comment: `id` should be `unique`...you can't have all those select with the same `id`...try using a `class` instead

Comment: Which element has id `choose`? If you have multiple elements with same ids, better use class instead of id.

Comment: You're using `id` for multiple elements, thus it just selects the first one it finds and applies. You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks you guys resolved when I changed to class

Answer (score 0):

The issue effectively was using ID instead of a class name

my code was rendering the lists using this code :

```
<select id="choose" name="type">
      <option disabled selected value>Catégorie</option>
      <option value="1">0-1000</option>
      <option value="2">1000-5000</option>
      <option value="3">5000-10000</option>
      <option value="4">10000-++</option>
</select></td>
```

after changing the ID by a class name :

```
<select class="choosable" name="type">
</select>
```

and updating the jQuery to :

```
$('.choosable').change(function(event){
        var categorie = $('.choosable').val();
```

It's resolved now.

Credits : [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) | [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/hackerman) | [Saket Santosh Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5913204/saket-santosh-patel) | [Akar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709111/akar)